# Why does my S3 presigned URL not work after changing the client's time?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-js

I am working on a project, where I need to fetch the presigned URL for a PDF in a private S3 bucket via React Native.

I'm using [`aws-sdk(v2.1381.0)`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-sdk).

I've set the expiry parameter as 24 hours. The URL is working correctly however when the user changes the time of the device more than 15 mins, I get an `cannot create document: pdf is corrupted` error.

The URL is getting constructed correctly with device's set time as creation timestamp in url, e.g.

> https://testbucket.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/app/pdfs/3/36/1.pdf?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIASGNP74JE2BKWOKXO%2F20231025%2Fap-south-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20231025T111403Z&X-Amz-Expires=86400&X-Amz-Signature=7e188762d6669cfb3aed24c1120e892cdbf05ab0850296baa39de5cfa05b06df&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host

`X-Amz-Date` is `25-10-23 16:44` which is the device's current time, however the actual current time is `25-10-23 16:28`.

According to documentation, the URL should be valid for 24 hrs from the time it was created irrespective of server time.

Can anyone please explain why is this happening?

Comment: S3 in general validates the request time against the actual time and returns [RequestTimeTooSkewed](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/ErrorResponses.html) if they differ by too much.  This check is not optional.

Comment: @AnonCoward I got the problem. So if I want to get urls for pdf without consideration of actual time and expiry time, what will be the best option

Comment: Make the object public.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when the user changes the time of the device more than 15 mins, I get an `cannot create document: pdf is corrupted` error.

This is due to clock skew.

If the client's time is different from AWS's time by more than about [15 minutes](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/clock-skew-correction/), the S3 API will reject the requests your application makes with the [`RequestTimeTooSkewed`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/ErrorResponses.html#ErrorCodeList) error code and `403 Forbidden`.

> According to documentation, the URL should be valid for 24 hrs from the time it was created irrespective of server time.

Incorrect, that is **not** mentioned in the documentation.

Allowing unlimited clock skew defeats the purpose of a presigned URL which is to provide a *limited* window of access.

The server time is thus important.

Comment: Alright I can understand that time difference should not be more than 15 minutes, there is one more issue that still persists. As I have given the expiry time as 24 hrs, if I choose any time in between the current time and past time in 24 hrs range then url still works. How come this works?

Comment: What do you ‘choose any time’? Can you give me an example?

Comment: I got the answer even though time is set to 22 hrs in the past and url is generated for that time but expiry time is set for 24 hrs hence it works at the current time

Comment: Correct, as long as you’re within the window, the URL will work as it’s all self-contained.